# Phonegap App not including javascript files

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Javascript files are not being pulled into my Phonegap app. This is a recent problem that is quite frankly driving me insane. This is the top of my index.html file:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD90W6MypWGP6s4luD2kQHhZ9IFQrfr04g&sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebook.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

This is my facebook.js file that I'm trying to pull in:

```
$(document).on('ready' , function(){
console.log('ready')

function onDeviceReady(){

console.log('test')

var plugin = new CC.CordovaFacebook();

plugin.init('***************', 'myapp', 
    ['email'], 
    function(response){console.log(response)}, 
    function(failure){console.log(failure)});

var loginButton = $('#login-with-facebook');

loginButton.on('click' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    plugin.login(function(token) {
        console.log("Access token is: " + token);
    }), function(failure){console.log(failure)});

})


}
if (window.cordova.logger) {window.cordova.logger.__onDeviceReady();};
onDeviceReady();
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 

})
```

I can't console.long anything in the facebook.js file. What's driving me even more crazy is that it's worked on occasion. Are my files out of order? Also, I only seem to be running into this issue after installing one of the cordova facebook plugins. Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Because you define your onDeviceReady function inside an anonymous event handler function, it won't be available until the DOM is loaded (and shouldn't only be accessible from within the event handler. This would only work properly if the device is ready before the DOM loads and only because onDeviceReady is manually invoked in the onDocumentReady event handler. Replace your facebook.js with the following.

```
function onDeviceReady(){

  console.log('test')

  var plugin = new CC.CordovaFacebook();

  plugin.init('443530475777959', 'spencerspiegelapp', 
      ['email'], 
      function(response){console.log(response)}, 
      function(failure){console.log(failure)});

  var loginButton = $('#login-with-facebook');

  loginButton.on('click' , function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      plugin.login(function(token) {
          console.log("Access token is: " + token);
      }), function(failure){console.log(failure)});

  })
}

$(document).on('ready' , function() {
  console.log('ready')
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 

  if (window.cordova.logger) {
    window.cordova.logger.__onDeviceReady();
  }
});
```